# How do I convert my design from a rectange to a different shaped template before printing?

Tags: print-design, logo, resize, affinity-designer, template-design

Client asked me to prepare a rectangular design for their new stubby coolers. After the design was approved, they have decided to add a second option for schooners.

I am not sure how to go about converting my original design to the new template provided by the printer. The design will fit of course, I'm more confused about how to set up the template with what I have been provided.

I am using Affinity Designer, but I can figure out a workaround if you wish to provide tips using Adobe CC.

Many thanks in advance.

[image: Stubby Cooler - Final Design for Bottle]

[image: Stubby Cooler - Template for Schooner]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I might be okay. I opened the document from the printer and noticed that the template has individual layers that can be resized accordingly.

At first I embedded the PDF into my other document and it flattened everything.

So I’ll just copy my design onto the template and resize as necessary.

Rookie mistake on my behalf smh.

[image: Individual Layers Available]